# Howto install single language of multilingual WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, installation, multilingual

I have a WinForms application, which I need to support in multiple languages. I would love to have a possibility to offer to the user during the installation setup (default Visual studio setup project) selection of a language he wants to install. Afterwards, application will use this language rather than choosing language based on system language.

Currently, I have application localized with standard WinForms localization + some custom resources for messages. This will produce satellite assemblies for me.

What would be the best practice for what I would like to achieve?

Best,
Jozef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a first shot i would save the selected language in the registry or the .config file.

Then within the program.cs before starting `Application.Run()` i would read this information and change the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to this setting.

Comment: Yep, thanks Oliver that would do it.
Do you have one more hint for the case where I do not want to have satellite assemblies ... if only one language is desired I do not need others, just one default language with resources build in in assembly just like the default case... Is it somehow doable?

Comment: To get the assembly into your executable you should take a look into [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en).